# NiFi 1.19.1 - InvokeHTTP POST not sending all headers

Tags: http-headers, apache-nifi

I have files I'm sending between clusters so I'm using InvokeHTTP to send to a load balancer on another cluster. I can get the files to send, but not all the headers are being send. I specified the headers to send in "Request Headers Attributes Pattern", but the only ones not arriving on the other side are ones which contain capitol letters. For example "header.type" is fine, but "header.Date" is not. The files arrives on the other cluster with "header.type" but not "header.Date". The header values are not ones I set, they are on the files when I receive them, so I'm just trying to forward the files. The second cluster is being used to test, so it needs to be able to handle the file exactly as the primary cluster gets them, and we use some of the headers with capitol letters in them.

Any advice on getting the headers with capitol letters to go? I've used .* and I've explicitly named the attributes to send (e.g. header.type|header.Date).

Answer (score 0):

@Ginger

The regex here is Case Sensitive.    If you cant explicitly define them, and you cant just set them manually as properties, then try what I found below.

I dont want to just link off stack, but @matt talks about another solution off stack:

> There are multiple EL functions you can use here:
> 1:

> ${http.headers.x-My-Header:isNull():ifElse('${http.headers.x-my-header}','${http.headers.x-My-Header}'):......}

> In above if subject "http.headers.x-My-Header" does not exist on the FlowFile it returns the value from "http.headers.x-my-header" attribute instead; otherwise it returns value from "http.headers.x-My-Header".  Then you can continue the EL statement to do whatever additional manipulation needed.

> 2:

> ${allMatchingAttributes('(?i)http.headers.x-my-header'):join(''):....}
> In above it uses a case insensitive Java regular expression within the "AllMatchingAttribtes( )" EL function to return values from all FlowFile attributes that satisfy that regex and then use the "join( )" function to merge them all together.  Since we expect that only one attribute will actually match, the result is just a single value.  This may be best option.

> 3:

> ${http.headers.x-My-Header:replaceNull(${http.header.X-my-header:replaceNull(${http.headers.x-my-header})}):....}
> In above we chain multiple "replaceNull( )" functions to iterate through all case permutations till we find one that exist as an attribute on the FlowFile.

> Note: In any of the above you would replace that last ":...." with the rest of your EL statement fucntions needed to manipulate the subject returned as you need.

> Options 1 and 3 require you to know all case permutations that may exist.
> Option 2 may be best choice as you do not need to know all the permutations, but can be an issue if for some reason you have multiple permutations of the same attribute on the same FlowFile.

Reference Link: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/HandleHttpRequest-and-header-case-sensitivity/m-p/310491